# Nothing happens when I press Sign in Button in Office365 Outlook Email Adapter configuration in BizTalk Server 2016

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

We are using BizTalk Server 2016 and I installed Future Pack 3 to test the Office365 Outlook Email adapter. I wanted to create a send port and select this adapter. I press the configure button to configure adapter and in this panel, I pressed sign in button to enter my credentials. But nothing happens when I press sign in button, No frame no popup. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Any errors in the event logs? I saw someone comment on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/biztalk/core/office365-mail-adapter that they were getting a SSO Audit error

Comment: Have you installed BizTalk TMS as mentioned here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/office365-adapters

Comment: Came across this issue myself yesterday - the documentation is a mess for this stuff. Worth mentioning that the attachment tab is absent in 2016 as its only applicable to BT 2020, another thing not made clear in many tutorials!

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?  I've hit the same one, and yes, I have installed BizTalk TMS

Answer (score 3):

To use Office 365 Adapters, install BizTalk TMS.

BizTalk Server TMS is a service that refreshes the Office 365 OAuth tokens used by BizTalk. It refreshes these tokens periodically, ensuring that the tokens always remain valid. It has a dependency on Enterprise Single Sign On service (ENT SSO), and must be installed on a computer that hosts the master secret server.

Please go through this article - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/office365-adapters

Comment: Quick note:  For BizTalk 2016, Run BizTalkTMS.msi from the BizTalk folder to add the "BizTalk TMS" Service.  I think for 2020 it's in the Configure.exe utility.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by someone in the comments. I recreated this in my local machine and first just installed the Feature Pack 3. If I only do that, the behavior mentioned in the post was recreated.

Then I installed BizTalkTMS and it resolved the problem.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/biztalk/core/office365-adapters

Answer (score 0):

One further thing that will prevent the button from working is if the server has not been configured to use TLS 1.2 in prefrence, this will also silently error.

As per [BizTalk Office365 email adapter not doing anything when sign-in button is clicked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1136116/biztalk-office365-email-adapter-not-doing-anything.html)

And as perarticle it links to [BizTalk Server Logic App Adapter: An error occurred while making the HTTP request. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case](https://blog.sandro-pereira.com/2020/02/09/biztalk-server-logic-app-adapter-an-error-occurred-while-making-the-http-request-this-could-be-due-to-the-fact-that-the-server-certificate-is-not-configured-properly-with-http-sys-in-the-https-case/) you need to make sure TLS 1.2 is enabled and SchUseStrongCrypto enabled in the registry keys

The User setting up the the port also needs to be a SSO Administrator, otherwise that will throw an error (in the Windows Events).