# BizTalk 2016 - BizTalk Server TMS failed to start

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

Regarding BizTalk 2016, this seems like it should be dead simple, but failing with a security error.

Documentation basically says "Enter the username and password of a user that's a member of the SSO Administrators group."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/install-and-configure-biztalk-tms-for-fp

I ran BizTalkTMS.msi (to install the Token Manager Service) under my userid (which is also a member of the SSO Admin group as defined in the BizTalk configureation.exe program.  It prompts for user/pass to under which the service should run. I put the exact same account "domain\user" that is running the Enterprise SSO and supposedly the correct password.

It returns the error: "BizTalk Server TMS failed to start. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services."

If I'm using the exact same account that is running Enterprise SSO, how could this happen?  We've tried about 3 other IDS, and they all give the same error.  What could be missing?

Trying to set this up to resolve issue: "Office365 Outlook Email - Sign-In button on Receive Location does nothing" (similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51209788/nothing-happens-when-i-press-sign-in-button-in-office365-outlook-email-adapter-c))

[image]

Comment: This will probably get closed as it isn't about programming.   Have you tried running BizTalkTMS.msi as Admin?

Comment: Thanks. This morning I had tried that, and with a differ user.  Then in a webex with a colleague today, we did it with the SSO user (he had the password), but we didn't do "run as admin".  So just now I did that combination, and it opened the vault, so to speak!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use both the user that is in the SSO group, and run BizTalkTMS.msi as an administrator.  Either do "run as admin" on it, or open a command prompt as admin, then run it from there.